# Binder.bindToState, link input as string

Tags: reactjs

```
<input type="number" valueLink={Binder.bindToState(this,"user", "meta_data.age")}/>
```

at state.
How it should be -`duration:120`
how it is - `duration:"120"` -

It stores value on as string. But I want it to be Number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs say that the `bindToState` also can accept a [converter](https://github.com/rsamec/react-binding#value-converters) function which in your case can be written like:

```
var converter = {
      parse: function (input) {
        if (!input) return undefined;
        return parseInt(input, 10)
      }, format: function (input) {
        if (!input) return undefined;
        return input.toString();
      }
    }
```

and used:

```
<input valueLink={Binder.bindToState(this, "user", "meta_data.age", converter)}/>
```